# Multiple loops with data.table in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, data.table, dt

I try to deal with multiple loops with data.table for quite some time and got frustrated. With sql it seamed quite intuitive, but with R I experience some problems.

For example, I would want to fread one txt file (as I have hundreds of files, each around 1 GB), make the calculations (sum price and quant, when time>my.time and for some selected isin's, grouped by my.time, isin and price), write the results to some csv file, remove original txt file from R memory; then redo these calculations one-by-one for all txt files and append the output csv file.

Lets start with the example data (quite small, just two identical files for illustration):

```
        time<-format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "1 sec"),"%H:%M:%S")
        n<-length(time)
        isin<-paste("US",1:n,sep="")
        price<-rnorm(n,101,1)
        quant<-rnorm(n,5,1)
        dt<-data.table(time,isin,price,quant)
        write.table(dt,"raw.txt",append = FALSE,sep = ",",col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
        write.table(dt,"raw2.txt",append = FALSE,sep = ",",col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

    my.files <- list.files(pattern = "raw*.txt")
    my.time<-format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "5 min"),"%H:%M:%S")
    my.isin<-c("US100","US150","US225","US250","US1050")
```

Then I try these 2 simple loops:

```
       for (i in my.files){
              for (j in my.time){
              dt<-fread(i)
        write.table(dt[which(isin %in% my.isin & time>j),
           .(sprice=sum(price),squant=sum(quant),**time.my=j**), by = .(isin,price)],
           "output.csv",append = TRUE,sep = ",",col.names = TRUE)
        rm(dt) 
        }}
```

**Second edit:** The loop with j finally started working for me (due to the bolded part). Maybe it would be possible to work without for loops and get the same results?

Thanks very much for help!

Comment: at which point it not work for you? did you read warning and error you get in your code?

Comment: Yes, at first I get this message:  `Error in `[.data.table`(dt, which(isin %in% my.isin & time > my.time),  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (86401,1,86401). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (0).`

Comment: Ok, so it is complaining about your use of `j` in `by`. Maybe you need to go back and think what you were trying to do with it there..? (Most of your code is very different from what I usually see, so I don't really get it.)

Comment: I want to build cumulative trade statistics every 5 minutes: I tried to find sum of all prices and quantities of some selected Isin's, where actual trade time is higher than my defined time interval (every 5 minutes). And the results should be grouped by Isin, unique price (as there could be same prices) and defined time (every 5 minutes).

Comment: @Linas instead of extra loop (every 5 min) you may try using non equi join on time column. Also do not group on double data type (floating point) like "price", format it to defined precision when doing grouping.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I still do not understand and know how to write such R code... maybe tapply (or other function from apply family) could help?

Comment: @Linas Can you post an example of the output you would like? I think that will help us understand what you are trying to accomplish with that loop. I am also confused. My thoughts thus far are to convert time to numeric so we can %between%.

Comment: I'm not sure about your sample data. There seems to be one for every second. Is that right?

Comment: @theArun Yes, the sample data could be millions of records (multiple seconds) for every bond - like an actual trading book. But I was able to produce only this :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is the output of your `which` statement is returning zero rows. First I would convert your time to `time` type. I've then created a 5 minute grouping variable.

This would first aggregate your tables.

```
dt[,`:=`(time= as.ITime(strptime(time, format="%H:%M:%S")))]
dt[,`:=`(time5 = format(strptime("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC") + 
                          round(as.numeric(time)/300)*300,"%H:%M"))]

dt[, list(sprice = sum(price),squant= sum(quant)),by = c("time5","price","isin")][isin %in% my.isin]


#    time5     price    isin    sprice   squant
# 1: 00:00 102.46668     US1 102.46668 3.002960
# 2: 00:00  99.02186     US2  99.02186 5.253252
# 3: 00:00 100.23665     US3 100.23665 6.153950
# 4: 00:00 102.21466     US4 102.21466 3.461051
# 5: 00:00 100.97890     US5 100.97890 5.893336
```

you can then filter it by your `my.isn` or time5 greater than custom times?

Comment: Thanks theArun! But what does t1 mean in Your example?

Comment: ah, sorry. that's `time`

Comment: Thanks again. But I need to compare time with some “external” vector that is not in the data table (as I need to work this way with my original data), i.e. without doing the second step (creating time5). Something like this (we can remove isin for simplicity): 
`my.time<-format(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()+1), by = "5 min"),"%H:%M:%S")`
and then `dt[, list(sprice = sum(price),squant= sum(quant)),by =c("my.time","price")][time>my.time]`
But I get this error again: `The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (289,86401). Each must be same length...`

Comment: That's probably cause, `my.time` is a list of length 28986401 variables. its a lot of variables to group by. you can create the my.time in the data.table.

Comment: @Arun. `my.time` is actualy only 289 length (there is a comma between 289,86401). I tried also to create another data table with my specified time `my.time.dt<-data.table(my.time)`, but this does not help when I try to run `dt[, list(sprice = sum(price),squant= sum(quant)),by = c("my.time.dt","price")][time>my.time.dt]`. Error: `by=c(...), key(...) or names(...) must evaluate to 'character'`. Maybe it would be possible to use apply for this loop?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the role of `by` .by is a group by function for within the dataset itself.

Comment: I finally wrote the for loop with j  - I edited the question to make it clearer. But maybe it would be possible to work without for loop, but get the same results as I can get with this or loop? As the speed is very bad...